# Symfony2 Form, How do I customize?

Tags: forms, symfony

To render a form, within a .twig template I have:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.title) }}
{{ form_row(form.description) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I get

```
<form name="job" method="post" action="/myname/Job/create">

<div><label for="job_title" class="required">Title</label>
<input type="text" id="job_title" name="job[title]" /></div>

<div><label for="job_description" class="required">Description</label>
<input type="text" id="job_description" name="job[description]" /></div>
</form>
```

but I need to render it something like:

```
<form name="job" method="post" action="/myname/Job/create">

<div><label for="job_title" class="required">Title</label>
<input type="text" id="job_title" name="job[0][title]" /></div>

<div><label for="job_description" class="required">Description</label>
<input type="text" id="job_description" name="job[0][description]" /></div>
</form>
```

the point being to insert the index [0]. (This I need to apply a JS trick)

I looked at `form_div_layout.html.twig`, I understand that the rendering of a form is given by the lines under `{%- block widget_attributes -%}`, but I do not see how Symfony 2.7 assigns that piece of html to `{{ full_name }}`.

Comment: can you show complete code for the form and what are you trying to achieve ? this is not helping in any way.

Comment: @satin, I tried to ask with more detail. I assume readers know Symfony.

Comment: what kind of js trick? Why do you want to make a two dimensional array from the formfields? You should leave the names as they are. you should refer by the id of the formfield inside the javascript code.

Comment: @Frankbeen I have a JS little script to clone a form in a page, and I would like to use it with Symfony too. Are you saying that what I am asking does not fit with Symfony? If so, why?

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript to add a class, an attribute or something like that to perform the same operation? Changing the HTML because of Javascript is too complex IMHO.

Comment: @A.L  Actually, I could use _prototype_ variables as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype), but I would like to use my own JS. However, I have a slightly different issue too: how do I define form and controller to (dynamically) create many objects of an entity at once. It does not seem that Symfony provides a plug&play way of doing that, does it?

Comment: @mario maybe you're looking for a collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: @A.L. Apparently, that does not work for the root object, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463227/symfony2-how-do-i-define-form-and-controllers-to-dynamically-create-multiple-o)

Comment: @A.L. by the way, by a var_dump($request), I see there the values from the form. I do not see how to extract them from $request and make them available to my controller (hope I explained myself). Do you happen to know?

Comment: @mario Please edit your question in order to add more information. You can fetch the data from a GET or POST request: http://www.symfony2cheatsheet.com/#controller

Comment: @A.L Thanks for the link, very useful. A [related question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463227/symfony2-how-do-i-define-form-and-controllers-to-dynamically-create-multiple-o/35501940#35501940) makes this one kind of obsolete.