# Symfony2 - How do I define Form and Controllers to dynamically create multiple objects of a entity at once?

Tags: forms, symfony

Symfony2 2.7

I have looked around, but I do not find a neat, standard way to define:

(*) a form (formType) and whatever controller you need to let a user to create dynamically and at once as many objects as she wishes.

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371638/symfony2-multiple-entities-of-same-class-in-one-form-solved?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953858/how-to-create-a-form-with-multiple-rows-of-one-entity-in-symfony2?rq=1), but I am not able to reproduce their solutions.

Question is: is there a standard way to do (*)?

Note: [This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) does not seem to help, in the sense that it creates only a unique Task object, even if it let a user to create (dynamically) several Tag ones.

PARTIAL SOLUTION
The following works fine: a user may add as many objects as she wishes.

I need to check whether I may clean the code somehow.
If you see a way to improve it, please comment.

Eventually, I wish to have a Job 1:M Tasks 1:M Tags situation, with a form to create at once many Jobs, many Tasks for each Job, many Tags for each Task.  I need to check that I may embed forms for the related 1:M entities. Stay tuned!

Controllers

```
/**
 * Creates a new Job entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="Myname_Job_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("MynameBlogBundle:Job:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    ////var_dump($request); die('here'); // this helped a lot to understand
    $postData = $request->request->get('form');
    $entity = array();
    foreach($postData['jobs'] as $key => $obj){$entity[$key]= new Job();}
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
       try {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            foreach($entity as $ent){ $em->persist($ent); }
            $em->flush();  

        } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
    }
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Myname_Job'));
    }
    return array(
        'info' =>   $postData,
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Job entity.
 *
 * @param Job $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Array $jobs)
{
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('jobs'=>$jobs))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('Myname_Job_create'))
            ->add('jobs','collection',array(
                'required'       => true,
                'allow_add'      => true,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'type'           => new JobType(),
           ))
            ->add('submit', 'submit',array('label' => 'Create'))
            ->getForm()
        ;

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Job entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="Myname_Job_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{


    $jobs = array(0 => new Job());
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($jobs);

    return array(
        'entity' => $jobs,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

JobType

```
class JobType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
  * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
  * @param array $options
  */

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Write Title   ',
            'required' => true
        ))
        ->add('description','text',array(
            'label'     => 'Write Descr.  ',

        )) 
    ;
}
....
}
```

New .twig  template

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
     {{ parent() }}

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mynameblog/js/JQuery/jquery-2.1.0.js') }}" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
var $collectionHolder;

// setup an "add aJobs" link
var $addJobLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_Job_link">Add Jobs</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addJobLink);

      function addJobForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
// Get the data-prototype explained earlier
var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

// get the new index
var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

// Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
// instead be a number based on how many items we have
var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

// increase the index with one for the next item
$collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

// Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a Jobs" link li
var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
$newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    }

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Get the ul that holds the collection of Jobs
$collectionHolder = $('ul.jobs');

// add the "add Jobs" anchor and li to the Jobs ul
$collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

// count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
// index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
$collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

$addJobLink.on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
    e.preventDefault();

    // add a newJobs form (see next code block)
    addJobForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
});
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block main -%}  
 <h1>Job creation</h1>

{{ form_start(form) }}

<ul class="jobs" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.jobs.vars.prototype)|e }}">

{# render the job-s only two fields: title description #}

{% for f in form.jobs %}
           <li>   {{ form_row(f) }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {{ form_end(form) }}
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think there is no way to create a prototype for a "root" form.
You should create one and copy the inputs with javascript, changing the inputs names. Then in you controller you have to count the posted parameters and rebuild your extended form before binding the form with your request.

Comment: @Alsatian, Thanks. I am not sure how to change inputs names, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443980/symfony2-form-how-do-i-customize). Also, what do you mean by to rebuild my _extended_ form?

Comment: @Alsatian, is my code something along your lines? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Advice : Best way to add several objects with one client action :**

- Create a form for each object (just duplicate it with JS)
- With JS, listen to the submit button and send each form with a different ajax request.

So it is very simple ...
No need to have a complicated form por to manage serveral entities in the controller receiving the posted request.

**But, To do what your want to do :**

Here is a way to do what you want.
I have only highlighted how to adapt the form on the server side.
I cannot test your JS, and here I'm assuming it add fields like [title_1,description_1,title_2,description_2,...] in your form.

You should also adapt :

- How you create your entities
- How you validate them

I suggest you to adapt your form with an option "objects_count" :
(notice that you should deal with a form without class (data_class should not be defined in configureOptions))

```
class JobType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
  * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
  * @param array $options
  */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // This is called once you posted your form to recreate the JS generated
        // fiels on the server side. Otherwise, these fiels are ignorated
        if($options['objects_count']>0){
            for($i=0;$i<$options['objects_count'];$i++){
                $builder
                    ->add('title_'.$i, TextType::class)
                    ->add('description_'.$i, TextType::class) 
                ;
            }
        }

        // This is called to render the first form
        else{
            $builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class)
                ->add('description', TextType::class) 
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('objects_count'=>0));
    }
}
```

Then, to deal with this form you have to get the count of posted fields :

Your controller :

```
/**
 * Creates a new Job entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="Myname_Job_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("MynameBlogBundle:Job:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $i = 1;
    $defaults = array();
    while($request->request->has('title_'.$i)){
        $defaults += array('title_'.$i=>"",'description_'.$i=>"");
        $i++;
    }


    $objects_count = $i-1;
    if($objects_count === 0){
        $defaults = array('title'=>"",'description'=>"");
    }


    $form = $this->$defaults(JobType::class,$defaults,array('objects_count'=>$objects_count));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Alsatian.Thanks so much. As soon as I have some spare time I'll look at it. Do you think it works for Symfony 2.7 too? (I am not going to update to v3 in the near future).

Comment: Yes it should work in Sf 2.7. Just use type's name instead of type's classes.